# Indexing metadata field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a metadata field inside the model I'm indexing, but when I index a field inside metadata that was previously indexed as another type, I get a "no mapping" error... How can I disable the dynamic mapping of the metadata field only?

If I previously indexed this document:

```
{
   ...
   "metadata": {
      "key": {
         "value": "test"
      }
   },
   ...
}
```

Then, if I index this document:

```
{
   ...
   "metadata": {
      "key": "test"
   },
   ...
}
```

I get the "tried to parse as object, but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?" error because metadata[key] is no longer an object. But this might happen when indexing metadata.

Thanks,

Pedro

Comment: Could you please provide your document structure and current mapping? More information we can base an answer on the better.

Comment: I added some examples. The current mapping is the _default_ mapping. I tried changing the mapping to `dynamic: strict` but I still get the "tried to parse as object, but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?" error.